# how to append QTextBrower in real time

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pymysql

I inherited PyQt5 class to make mysql insert program. so i used pymsql too.
This is the part of insert class.

```
for index, row in input_df.iterrows():
   values = tuple(np.insert(row.values, 0, index))
   try:
      self.cur.execute(insert_sql, values)
   except (pymysql.err.InternalError, pymysql.err.IntegrityError, pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) as e:
      code, msg = e.args
      print(code, msg)
      # self.textBrowser.append(msg)
      # self.textBrowser.append(code)
```

The problem is, if there's an error, it suddenly broke at append line. If i hide it and do with print function, there's no problem of running it.

Also, i put several self.textBrowser.append at other place but it runs after whole program end. I want append to be run on real time. How can I solve this?

I tried to mutual_lock and mutual_unlock up and under the append, but this doesn't work.

Comment: You're trying to do the above from an external thread, aren't you? If that's the case, remember that UI elements are ***NOT*** thread safe, and shall ***never*** be accessed outside the main thread. If you want to interact with the UI from another thread, you **must** use QThread and custom signals.

Comment: actually it was ongoing on main thread (i checked with pycharm, there was only one thread... so i think. it might be wrong.) the error was happenging because code was int, and i solved it. now it prints on qtextbrower. but i still have a hard time about error messages are not showing up real time. this is real problem with thread, right?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "this is real problem with thread", but in any case we cannot help you unless you provide a valid [mre].

Comment: I'm sorry for misunderstanding. the problem is that append on textbrower(qtextbrowser) does not work on time. In the for loop, append activate after for loop finish, not when for loop is running. (of course i erased annotation marks.)

Comment: Ok, so you mean that you expect the text to be updated progressively? That's not how event loops work: the UI can only be updated when control returns to it, and the for loop is obviously blocking. While it is possible to "force" the processing of queued events during a process that takes a lot of time (due to computation or I/O delays), it's normally discouraged (unless the blocking computation takes *a lot* of time) as it would actually slow down the process itself. So, if the loop above takes less than a few seconds, just leave things as they are. If it's longer, you may consider threading.

Comment: oh it slows down the process. that helps me decide how to do with this code. thank you anyway. how can i give you rewards of stackoverflow?

Comment: What could slow down is continuously trying to process events in the queue, if you have to process a loop that iterates thousands of times, that might impact performance unless you have a way to check only at larger intervals. You can't "reward" people, you can only accept answers (if actual answers are given) or eventually up vote them (if you have at least 50 reputation points). Please review the [tour] and check [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: Why not answer your own question?

Answer (score -1):

I figured out it won't be updated progressively thanks to musicamante. and i don't want to slow down the process so I just found other ways to show the program state.